# Error: Expected spy to have been called with [ Object(...) ] but it was never called. - Jasmine - Angular 16

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular16

I am writing a unit test for my Angular 16 project using Jasmine. However, I encounter the same problem in several components of the project. In this case I want to test that I get "X" message when I close my sidebar, but the test file always shows me this error:

> Error: Expected spy ConfirmationService.confirm to have been called
> with [ Object(...) ] but it was never called.

I tried this links:

- [Error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with: [ [ '/client/register' ] ] but it was never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430363/error-expected-spy-navigate-to-have-been-called-with-client-register)
- [Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ 'users' ] ] but it was never called in integration testing angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335028/expected-spy-navigate-to-have-been-called-with-users-but-it-was-never)

But I don't get **async** or **fakeAsynca** working either.

**SPEC.TS:**

```
describe('EditDeclarationComponent', () => {
  let component: EditDeclarationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditDeclarationComponent>;
  let installationServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<InstallationService>;
  let confirmationServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ConfirmationService>;
  let declarationServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DeclarationService>;

beforeEach(async () => {
    installationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('InstallationService', [
      'getInstallationsType',
      'existInstallationNPM',
      'saveInstalacion',
    ]);
    confirmationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfirmationService', [
      'confirm',
    ]);
    declarationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DeclarationService', [
      'updateDeclaration',
    ]);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [
      EditDeclarationComponent,
      NumberPipe,
      SgIconComponent,
      SgFormAddDeclarationDestinationComponent,
      SgButtonComponent,
    ],
      providers: [
        { provide: InstallationService, useValue: installationServiceSpy },
        MessageService,
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useValue: confirmationServiceSpy },
        { provide: DeclarationService, useValue: declarationServiceSpy },
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        DialogModule,
        DividerModule,
        ConfirmDialogModule,
        ToastModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        InputTextModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditDeclarationComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    installationServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(
      InstallationService
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<InstallationService>;

    confirmationServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(
      ConfirmationService
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<ConfirmationService>;

    declarationServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(
      DeclarationService
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<DeclarationService>;

    installationServiceSpy.getInstallationsType.and.returnValue(of(response));

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

**TEST:**

```
   it('should set instalacionNew and dialogNewInstalacion correctly when accepted', () => {
      const mockConfirmationResponse: any = {
        accept: (callback: Function) => {
          callback();
        },
      };

      confirmationServiceSpy.confirm.and.callFake((options: any) =>
        options.accept(mockConfirmationResponse.accept)
      );

      component.onCancelNewInstallation();

      expect(component.instalacionNew).toEqual({} as Installation);

      expect(component.dialogNewInstalacion).toBe(false);

      expect(confirmationServiceSpy.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        message: 'Are you sure about exiting the reinstall window?',
        header: 'Exit new installation window?',
        icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
        acceptLabel: 'Yes',
        rejectLabel: 'No',
        accept: jasmine.any(Function),
      });

    });
```

**TYPESCRIPT:**

```
instalacionNew: Installation = {} as Installation;
dialogNewInstalacion: boolean = false;
(Installation is a model.ts with an object inside) 

 constructor(
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    private declarationService: DeclarationService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private installationService: InstallationService
  ) {}

 onCancelNewInstallation() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure about exiting the reinstall window?',
      header: 'Exit new installation window?',
      icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
      acceptLabel: 'Yes',
      rejectLabel: 'No',
      accept: () => {
        this.instalacionNew = {} as Installation;
        this.dialogNewInstalacion = false;
      },
    });
  }
```

I use this same function in another component, I run the same test and it doesn't give me an error, that's what I don't understand, that in some components yes and in others no. I have checked and I can't find any difference in the code and the calls, how could I solve it?

Comment: Can you try adding `EditDeclarationComponent` to the `declarations` array? The rest looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had it integrated, sorry I didn't put it so it won't be too long/confusing, I have already edited the post with the declarations.